# How do I stop a person from giving multiple answers to a question I asked a year ago

Tags: support

I asked a question on Christianity Stack a year ago and chose an answer as being the best.  A new contributor has now recently posted four different answers, some of which do not even address the question.  I've already asked them to select one answer and delete the rest, but to no avail.  More answers keep turning up!  Can the community protect my answer to prevent this unwanted attention?

Comment: You can make a custom flag on an answer to ask for it to be protected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two options:

1. **Downvote**

   If someone is posting bad answers, downvote and they'll eventually find themselves [answer banned](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/help/answer-bans).
2. **Flag**

   If they're posting non-answers flag 'em and mod's will have to deal on a case-by-case basis.  If it's harassment, then expect them to be booted (for a time) from the site immediately. If they persistently offer non-answers after being asked to stop then they'll probably be booted as well.

Caleb explained a case where just downvoting is not a great idea because it often makes it harder for mods to find, but I can't recall the reasoning behind it, hopefully he chimes in as well.

Comment: The slightly counter-intuitive instance where downvoting is not recommended is in the case of questions that are outright spam. Those should be flagged using the spam flag tool. This facilitates them getting deleted faster. The problem is that after a certain threshold the site starts hiding them from the home page (but not all pages). This has the effect of getting them out of the eyes of more people that could flag. The same number of spam flags instead of downvotes would cause the post to be deleted outright rather that just removed from prominence, downvotes can cause them to linger.

Comment: Appreciate the assistance of both Peter Turner and Caleb. Thank you.